# Dificuldade ao Deletar casos em Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou começando estudar Javascript e estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web, em que uma ONG se cadastra e pode criar casos. Estou usando o Insomnia para testar as requisições HTTP. Entretanto, ao tentar deletar um caso, o Insomnia carrega a requisição e não tem retorno, e no terminal do VS Code, tenho a seguinte mensagem:

```
(node:9328) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: ong is not defined
    at delete (C:\Semana OmniStack\www\semanaomnistack11\aulas\backend\src\controllers\IncidentController.js:50:31)
(node:9328) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an 
async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9328) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.*
```

PS: todas as outras requisições funcionam, exceto essa. O método delete é o seguinte:

```
 async delete(request, response) {
     const { id } = request.params;
     const ong_id = request.headers.authorization;

     const incident = await connection('incidents')
         .where('id', id)
         .select('ong_id')
         .first();

     if (incident.ong_id != ong.id) {
         return response.status(401).json({ error: 'Operation not permitted.' });
     }

     await connection('incidents').where('id', id).delete();

     return response.status(204).send();
}
```

Comment: Será que em vez de `ong.id` deverias ter `ong_id` aqui `if (incident.ong_id != ong.id) {`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No erro é apontado que "*ong is not defined*" (a variável *ong* não está definida).
Note que no seu código você tenta comparar `incident.ong_id` com `ong.id`, mas em nenhum momento você obtém e/ou instancia *ong*.
Acredito que foi um erro de digitação, já que você obtém *ong_id*.
Então teoricamente seria só substituir:

```
incident.ong_id != ong.id
```

por:

```
incident.ong_id != ong_id
```

Comment: Tem razão! Falta de atenção, obrigado!!

Answer (score 0):

Olá, basta substituir este trecho:

```
if (incident.ong_id != ong.id) {
     return response.status(401).json({ error: 'Operation not permitted.' });
 }
```

Por este:

```
if(incidents.ong_id != ong_id) {
            return response.status(401).json({ error: 'Operation not permitted.'});
        }
```

Provavelmente foi um erro de digitação na palavra incident, que o correto seria incidents (no plural).